# Use tmx file to create map in java

Tags: xml, javafx, tiled, tmx

I use Tiled to create tiled map.

I create tmx file but I don't know how I can use this file to create a tiled map in javafx.

I search and find I have to convert tmx file to XML file.

But I don't know how I use from the XML file.

please help me to create a tiled map from XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve in JavaFX but there is a thread in the tiled forum that seems to address your question:

http://discourse.mapeditor.org/t/loading-tmx-map-and-displaying-with-javafx/1189

Btw tmx files actually are XML files. TMX is short for Tile Map XML.

Comment: please present for me the required library.

Comment: He's using libtiled-java, which is since recently available in the Maven central repository: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mapeditor%22 It is still undergoing heavy work though, to make it up-to-date (see https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/pull/1637)